# How to update libnet-amazon-ec2-perl to latest version in sausy

Tags: 13.10

I have ubuntu saucy. 13.10. I have libnet-amazon-ec2-perl installed which is 0.23 in 13.10 saucy. How do I upgrade the libnet-amazon-ec2-perl to latest 0.24 version? I did try `sudo apt-get update` and installing. but it says it is up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS you have that version. You can wait until 14.04 LTS then by upgrading to it can you the desired version.

else you can download from

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libn/libnet-amazon-ec2-perl/libnet-amazon-ec2-perl_0.24-1_all.deb

just open your terminal and do as

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libn/libnet-amazon-ec2-perl/libnet-amazon-ec2-perl_0.24-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libnet-amazon-ec2-perl_0.24-1_all.deb
```

Thats it , it will install in your Ubuntu with desired version.